# in-pronunciation -- meaning?

Tags: meaning

Example ([short audio clip](http://vocaroo.com/i/s03GGF79gDx4)):

Transcript:

> SQL like the relational model has been around for decades and supports a many-billion-dollar market. The first thing you might be wondering is how you pronounce it. Is it "SQL" or is it "sequel"? My friends in industry tell me that "sequel" is the **in-pronunciation**. So, that's the one I'll be using. Now, SQL is supported by all major commercial database systems.

Did I get it right? Is that even a word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `the "in" pronunciation`. Notice the quotation marks around *in*. When something is "in", it is "in style" or is "in favor" with a certain group or number of people. Something that is "in" can also mean something that a group or number of people consider to be "cool" or correct (like which athletic shoes are "in" this year). But because styles, preferences, and coolness can change over time, something (even a pronunciation) can be "in" for a certain length of time and then "out" when sentiment or usage swings a different way.